# Javascript, проблема с потоками

Tags: javascript, node.js, потоки-данных, multer

Есть такой код:
Тут я создаю поток для подсчета хеш суммы.

```
getHashSummingStream(hashName) {
    const hash = crypto.createHash("md5");

    const hashStream = new stream.Transform({
        transform: (chunk, encoding, done) => {
            hash.update(chunk);
            done(null, chunk);
        },
    });

    return {hash, hashStream};
}
```

Тут для записи.

```
const writeStream = this.file.createWriteStream(tempPath);
```

Поток для чтения я получаю от [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)-а и подписываюсь на него. Все действие происходит в движке [мультера](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer), а именно в функции [_handleFile](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/StorageEngine.md)

```
const {hash, hashStream} = class.getHashSummingStream()

fileStream.on("end", async () => {
    const {newFileName, newPathWithFile} = await handleUploadedFile(hash);
});
```

И беру еще [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) поток, для сжатия картинок.

Использую так. (pipeline промисифицирована).

```
await stream.pipeline(fileStream, hashStream, sharpStream, writeStream)
```

В `handleUploadedFile`:

```
function handleUploadedFile(hash) {
    const md5Hash = hash.digest("hex");
    //Дальше тут идет обработка директории для хранения файлов. hash.digest не вызываю ни разу.
}
```

**Суть:**

Если убрать sharp stream, получаю такую ошибку:

```
internal/crypto/hash.js:79
throw new ERR_CRYPTO_HASH_FINALIZED();
Error [ERR_CRYPTO_HASH_FINALIZED]: Digest already called
at Hash.update (internal/crypto/hash.js:79:11)
at Transform.transform [as _transform] (file:///www/services/crypto.js:420:22)
at Transform._read (_stream_transform.js:205:10)
at Transform.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:481:10)
at flow (_stream_readable.js:992:34)
at WriteStream.pipeOnDrainFunctionResult (_stream_readable.js:816:7)
at WriteStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:461:12)
at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:446:7)
at internal/fs/streams.js:408:5
at FSReqCallback.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:638:5)
at FSReqCallback.callbackTrampoline (internal/async_hooks.js:129:14) {
code: 'ERR_CRYPTO_HASH_FINALIZED'
| }
```

Кратко: если [отсюда](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDRYL.png) убрать `sharp`, будет ошибка, что описана выше. (данный `массив` я раскладываю в `pipeline`)

**До смешного:**

```
const pipelina = promisify(pipeline);
await pipelina(fileStream, hashStream, sharp, writeStream);
```

Тут работает, если вывести результат `hash.digest("hex")`, хеш картинки совпадет.

А вот так:

```
await pipelina(fileStream, hashStream, writeStream);
```

Ошибка, и, даже хеш картинки не совпадает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил, подписавшись на окончание потока записи, вместо потока чтения, так:

```
writeStream.on("finish", async () => {
    const {newFileName, newPathWithFile} = await handleUploadedFile(hash);
});
```